# What it the name of the computer art that seems to zoom forever?

Tags: resource-recommendations, zoom

I was watching BBC Click today, and they showed this website where there was a picture that, when zoomed in, it does not get hazy.

You actually zoom straight into another picture, and this just goes on and on. It is like a sort of infinite zooming. **Could anyone tell me the name of this and even a place on the net where i can see this.**

Comment: You mean something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2H4yiIx9R-g?

Comment: I think they are often called infinite zoom pictures. --- They do not need to be generated from a computed model (like fractals) but they can be composed from multiple painted images like: https://youtu.be/UyXiWXIKEAk https://youtu.be/TuN3XAHZ80A or from multiple photographs / videos: https://youtu.be/BERnb9gBEi4 https://youtu.be/cDSc7K2Nz5k?t=32s --- You can notice that the first two examples can be shown in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see BBC Click. Images which are infinitely recursive are probably ***fractals*** (Wikipedia has articles on [fractals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal) and [fractal art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_art)).

An online zoomable gallery is available at http://www.fractal-recursions.com/files/zoom0001.html (in this gallery each level of zoom has separate images: there may well be a gallery elsewhere which actually zooms).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Zoomquilt](http://zoomquilt.org/)

It’s like  fractals except it’s with pictures I know what you’re talking about it’s mesmerizing you could just stare at it for hours

Answer (score 0):

These are simply called infinitely zooming images. They can be loopable or they can actually not be infinite in that they eventually end (but they are still commonly called "infinitely zoomable" if the zoom level is more than regular images).

You can create these through any means of creating images if you pair it with digital versions.

In recent years, these are often created using AI through techniques known as outpainting or inpainting, depending on the direction that one is adding detail to.

Answer (score -1):

This art is a function of generative-AI. I don't think it has a name yet but from what I've found it's primarily a function of Midjourney. I found this youtube video which explains it in detail including how it's created:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbsz7krG3M

Comment: This is one form of it but it is far from the only form